# Two-way data binding with DataSet and ADO.NET

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ado.net

I'm just beginning to explore WPF and its possibilities regarding data binding.

I've got a sample Access database file and put its content into a `DataSet`. Then I bind the `DataSet` to a Grid (two way binding). What I want to achieve is to update the underlying database entry of the changed `DataSet`-Item. This is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DataSet sampleDataSet;
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeDB();
    }

    private void InitializeDB()
    {
        string mdbFile = "./test.mdb";
        string connString = string.Format(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}", mdbFile);
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Player;", conn);

        // ----------------------
        // **EDIT** inserted update command

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Player SET Name = @Name " + 
                       "WHERE ID = @ID", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "Name");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Char, 5, "ID");

        // set the update command
        adapter.UpdateCommand = cmd;

        // **End of EDIT**
        // ----------------------

        sampleDataSet = new DataSet("Player Table");
        adapter.Fill(sampleDataSet, "Player");

        data1.DataContext = sampleDataSet;
    }

    private void data1_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit)
        {
            adapter.Update(sampleDataSet, "Player");
        }
    }

    // Edit Comment April, 14th - Begin
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //sampleDataSet.AcceptChanges();
        adapter.Update(sampleDataSet, "Player"); // Calling update again fixes it, but why?
    }
    // Edit Comment April, 14th - End
}
```

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="AdoTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="data1" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Player}" CellEditEnding="data1_CellEditEnding" />
</Grid>
```

What is the approach to actually persist the changed values in the grid to the database file?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Update Method of the DataAdapter. This will require you to set the InsertMethod, UpdateMethod and DeleteMethod properties with commands that do the actual inserts, updates and deletes. You could also use the [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx) to generate the queries for you as long as the select hits a single table (including its primary key or at least one unique column)
[See this too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx)

Another way woul dbe to use the entity framework and have that generate the queries for you.

**EDIT** on second thought, what is your question? You are already doing this (except for setting the update, insert and delete commands.)

[Look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afybt7wb.aspx) to see how to sync the database with the Dataset

Comment: You're right, I didn't know yet about what else had to be done. So now I defined an UpdateCommand (will add Insert and Delete later). Now, however, the last update I make is not persisted e.g. I make three updates, only the first two are actually stored to the database. Off by one, any idea?

Comment: Try the third update by hand (in some query tool) or as the only update in the query and see what potentially goes wrong. Feel free to post the update query you wrote.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Are you sure you are updating the correct data (feeding it the correct ID)?

Comment: Not sure how to debug the ID. Just seems that something needs to be reloaded. It's always "coming through" with the next update...

Comment: You mean that after the update you need to do a Fill to actually see the changes? See my update in my answer.

Comment: I used sampleDataSet.AcceptChanges() when closing the gui. Still having the same issue: What ever is the last line to be edited, the change will not be persisted. Any other idea?

Comment: Try editing a line, shifting focus to another line and then save. Does that save inlude the changes to the last edited line?

Comment: Just shifting the focus to another line doesn't help. I tried around for a bit, so far only calling again `adapter.Update(sampleDataSet, "Player")`, e.g. in Window_closing, does persist the last changed row. But this does not make sense to me.

Comment: Does shifting the focus to another control (not line) help?

Comment: No, that doesn't help either. I added a checkbox and made sure it had the focus. Same behaviour. The last change is not being persisted.

Comment: Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=Player is Player the name of the table or something else?